# I want to know how it's correct

Tags: grammar

WHICH FORM IS CORRECT:
I just want to inform you, or
I want just to inform you

Answer (score 1):

I just want to inform you.

Sometimes you can use google to auto complete your sentences in the search bar and most of the time it will give you a proper sentence. Use it next time.